# Rsync moving window of last k subdirectories

Tags: rsync

When rsyncing directory `src` to `dest`, is there any way I can make `dest` contain the last `k` sub-directories, in lexicographical order, of directory `src`, as in a moving window where sub-directories having fallen outside of the window are automatically removed from `dest` when re-running the same command at a later time?

For example, if `k` = 2, `src` contains

```
dir_1
dir_2
dir_3
dir_4
dir_5
```

and `dest` is empty, after running `rsync`, `dest` should contain `dir_4` and `dir_5`. When, at a later time `src`, contains

```
dir_1
dir_2
dir_3
dir_4
dir_5
dir_6
```

and `rsync` is run again (with the very same command line), I want `dir_4` to be deleted from `dest`, replaced by `dir_6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

A `/bin/sh` solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

# number of entries to sync
k=2

# generate file list (sets $1, $2, $3 etc., collectively known as $@)
set -- src/*

# shift off all but the last $k of these entries
shift "$(( $# - k ))"

# create include patterns ($entry is not actually used,
# we work on the 1st element and then add it to the end and shift)
for entry do
    set -- "$@" --include="${1##*/}/***"
    shift
done

# run rsync
rsync --verbose --archive --delete --delete-excluded "$@" --exclude='*' src/ dest/
```

This creates a list of files in `$@` with `set` first (this list is sorted lexicographically, because globs do that), then removes all but the last `$k` of these. The loop converts each `src/element` into `--include=element/***`. This inclusion pattern will make `rsync` consider the named `element` and anything below it.  These inclusion patterns are used on the `rsync` command line together with `--exclude='*'` which will exclude everything not explicitly included (first match matters).

The `rsync` run uses `--delete` which will delete anything in the included subdirectories on the destination that is not available in the source directory, and `--delete-excluded` will additionally delete everything that was excluded.

Run the script with `sh -x` to see what happens.

You could do this in `bash` with arrays as well, but the syntax is a bit messy.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. While ``k`` is quite small in my case, the ``src`` directory contains tens of thousands of subdirectories, and I wonder whether this solution scales reliably. I had little luck finding out how many tokens ``$@`` can handle from the ``man`` pages.

Comment: @gd1 There should not be an issue with many subdirectories. The script will just use a bit of memory to store the pathnames as strings. The only issue is if `k` is _very_ large in which case the command line that runs `rsync` may be too long.  If you do run into issues, we would have to look at other solutions.

Comment: @gd1 In general though, I'd recommend to not have more than a thousand or so directory entries in any directory, if at all possible, as traversing huge directories is slow.  Utilities that does caching often has two or three levels of subdirectories in their top-level cache directory, for speed.